# MachineName field element: How do I use the source and exists properties?

Tags: forms, webforms

In my custom form, I am trying to create webform entities. Since webforms need unique machine names, I'm using the MachineName (machine_name) form element. The D8 MachineName element documentation suggests that we can get the field to auto-populate based on the text input of another field, AND there can be an AJAX callback to call a function that can check to see if the machine name is unique.

Neither is working for me. These are the form elements I am using.

```
//----------------- general settings ------------------
$form['settings'] = array(
  'label' => ['#type' => 'textfield','#title' => 'Form Title'],
  'id'=> array(
    '#type' => 'machine_name',
    'label' => 'hh',
    '#source' => ['label'],
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#description' => $this->t('A unique name for this item. It must only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores.'),
    '#machine_name' => array(
      'exists' => array(
        $this,
        'webform_id_exists',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Can anyone advise? I have a callback function named, but no idea what it should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can look at [Drupal\node\NodeTypeForm.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeTypeForm.php/class/NodeTypeForm/8.2.x) for an example.

We see the name and type fields defined like:

```
$form['name'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  // ...
);
$form['type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'machine_name',
  // ...
  '#machine_name' => array(
    'exists' => [
      'Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType',
      'load',
    ],
    'source' => array(
      'name',
    ),
  ),
  // ...
);
```

This shows us how to define the special machine_name type properties in the array. We can see that both exists and source are defined inside `#machine_name`. Additionally, we see that the exists callback is just calling the `NodeType::load()` (which is actually inherited straight from [Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity::load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8.2.x)).

For our exists callback, given this example, we'll want to use the equivalent method for whatever kind of entity we're creating a machine name for. Given your example, we're creating webforms, so we'd use the `Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load()` method for the exists callback.

We also see, from the [machine_name element documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21MachineName.php/class/MachineName/8.2.x), that the source property needs to be the `#array_parents` of the source field. Since your fields are nested inside `settings`, you'll need to include it in the source property.

Given the above, your updated code should be:

```
$form['settings'] = [
  'label' => [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Form Title'
  ],
  'id'=> [
    '#type' => 'machine_name',
    'label' => 'hh',
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#description' => $this->t('A unique name for this item. It must only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores.'),
    '#machine_name' => [
      'exists' => [
        'Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform',
        'load',
      ],
      'source' => [
        'settings',
        'label',
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: This works exactly as advertised.  I particularly appreciate that there is no need to create a local function to serve the :exists feature.